# SQL query to check the presence of a particular product in multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have 7 tables and each table will contain an entry for a particular product.I want to check whether all 7 tables contains entry for a particular ID(eg: 4562). ie, data exists or not.I am using SQL server 2008.Please help me to write a query to check the status.

Comment: If you do a basic join rather than left join, the product will only appear if it's in all of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a basic join rather than left join, the product will only appear if it's in all of the tables.

```
select * from tab1
join tab2 on tab2.id = tab1.id 
join tab3 on tab3.id = tab1.id 
join tab4 on tab4.id = tab1.id 
join tab5 on tab5.id = tab1.id 
Where tab1.id = 1234
```

etc etc

Comment: select * from tab1 join tab2 on tab2.id = tab1.id where tab2.id='121'?

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot the where clause

Comment: see if 5 tables how can i write?I am not familiar with joins

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command (example for 3 tables T1,T2,T3). It returns `1` if `ID = 4562` exists in ALL tables and `0` if at least one table miss this ID.

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN 
         (
              EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE ID=4562)
          AND EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM T2 WHERE ID=4562)
          AND EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM T3 WHERE ID=4562)          
         )
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0
       END AS [ID_Exists_in_all_tables]
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c412/2)</kbd>